# RPG game engine HTML5/javscript

Tags: javascript, html, game-development

I am planning to build a 2D RPG game (Zelda style). I am looking for a game engine that has the following features:

1. Map editor to create maps (preferably orthographic grid), with solid objects, doors/portals, items etc.
2. Mobs: Support for easily creating mob entities with basic properties (HP, speed, movement), and spawning them dynamically.
3. Support in all major browsers.
4. Basic algorithms like path-finding, collision detection, projectile shooting, etc.
5. Support for basic items like weapons, armor, potions etc.

These additional features would also be great to have:

1. Multiplayer, i.e. multiple people playing in the same map. (Not MMO... maybe 20-25 people at a time)
2. Inventory screen, where player can see the items they have picked up.

So basically, I just want to get the basics of a simple RPG game, so that I can focus on the layers on top. Please share any comments on whether ImpactJS would be suitable, its the best option I've found so far.

Answer (score 1):

Deepak, have you tried [Phaser](http://phaser.io/) ? Its a pretty neat engine. Though I haven't tried all the feature-requirements you have listed, in it, but estimating it to fit well.

[Here's a page](http://examples.phaser.io/) which demonstrates Phaser's capabilities with examples. A quick search revealed many pages with commentary on some of the other features you wanted. Eg: [this page](http://www.emanueleferonato.com/2014/08/13/how-to-create-an-html5-rpg-physics-driven-game-with-phaser/) discusses creating a RPG physics driven game.

Comment: You wrote you used the tool? What are your experiences? Which features of the OP did you use and how are they? Recommendations work best if they are personal, like you would tell a friend over a coffee.

Answer (score 0):

[Unity3d](http://unity3d.com/) is a pretty fantastic platform integrated development environment that allows you to code in multiple languages and export your project to an HTML web player.

Although its awesome power is daunting at first glance, it has a lot of basic, easy to follow [tutorials](http://unity3d.com/learn) to get you oriented and building fun 2D and 3D games in one day.

Comment: And then buy a [map editor](https://www.assetstore.unity3d.com/en/#!/content/25657) for 45 USD? Please enrich your answer with some details on how to achieve what OP needs